# Custome BaseAdapter position in getView is always 0

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-adapter

Hello i try to use my own adapter on `Gridview`.

My problem is that the position in getView is not increasing.

This is my code:

```
 public class WorkourLogBuilder {

     String[] values = new String[11];
     Context mContext;
     Map<Integer, String[]> valuesArray;
     int rowsCount = 0;
     int mode;
     int adappterRowsCount = 0;

     static final int AEROBIC = 1;
     static final int ANAEROBIC = 0;

     public WorkourLogBuilder(Context context, int modeChoosed)
     {
         mContext = context;
         mode = modeChoosed;
         valuesArray = new HashMap<Integer, String[]>();
     }

     public void commintRow()
     {
         valuesArray.put(rowsCount, values);

         rowsCount++;

         Log.i("rowsCount", rowsCount+"");

         values = new String[11];
     }

     public void setWorkoutWeight(String value)
     {
         values[0] = value;
     }

     public void setSets(String value)
     {
         values[1] = value;
     }

     public void setReps(String value)
     {
         values[2] = value;
     }

     public void setWorkTime(String value)
     {
         values[3] = value;
     }

     public void setWDayTime(String value)
     {
         values[4] = value;
     }

     public void setDistance(String value)
     {
         values[5] = value;
     }

     public void setSpeed(String value)
     {
         values[6] = value;
     }

     public void setRestTime(String value)
     {
         values[7] = value;
     }


     public void setCaloires(String value)
     {
         values[8] = value;
     }

     public void setHeartBeat(String value)
     {
         values[9] = value;
     }

     public void setComment(String value)
     {
         values[10] = value;
     }


     public View build()
     {
         LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();

         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.workout_log_row, null, false);

         GridView grid = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.table);

         Log.i("count", valuesArray.size()+"");

         grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());

         return v;
     }

        public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            public int getCount() {

                return (valuesArray.size()+6);
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return valuesArray.get(position);
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }


            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                Log.i("position", position+"");

                if(position < 6)
                {
                    ImageView image = new ImageView(mContext);

                    if(position < 3)
                        image.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.small_green_apple));
                    else
                        image.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.anonymous));

                    image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    return image;
                }

                TextView textValue = new TextView(mContext);

                textValue.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                GridView.LayoutParams lp = new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, GridView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                textValue.setLayoutParams(lp);

                String[] currecntRow = valuesArray.get(adappterRowsCount);

                switch(position % 6)
                {
                  case 0:
                  {
                      if(adappterRowsCount != 6)
                          adappterRowsCount++;

                      if(mode == AEROBIC)
                          textValue.setText(currecntRow[5]);
                      else
                          textValue.setText(currecntRow[0]);

                      break;
                  }

                  case 1:
                  {
                      if(mode == AEROBIC)
                          textValue.setText(currecntRow[3]);
                      else
                          textValue.setText(currecntRow[2]);
                      break;
                  }


                  case 2:
                  {
                      if(mode == AEROBIC)
                          textValue.setText(currecntRow[6]);
                      else
                          textValue.setText(currecntRow[1]);
                      break;
                  }

                  case 3:
                  {
                      if(mode == AEROBIC)
                          textValue.setText(currecntRow[1]);
                      else
                          textValue.setText(currecntRow[7]);
                      break;
                  }


                  case 4:
                  {
                      if(mode == AEROBIC)
                          textValue.setText(currecntRow[7]);
                      else
                          textValue.setText(currecntRow[3]);
                      break;
                  }

                  case 5:
                  {
                      if(mode == AEROBIC)
                          textValue.setText(currecntRow[10]);
                      else
                          textValue.setText(currecntRow[10]);
                      break;
                  }
                }


                return textValue;
            }


        }`enter code h
```

The XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:numColumns="6" >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is where i use `WorkourLogBuilder` class

```
public void setTheLogViewTest(String date)
    {
        String[][] values = data.dayLog(date);

        ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> listAll = new ArrayList<ExpandListGroup>();
        ArrayList<ExpandListChild> listChilds = new ArrayList<ExpandListChild>();
        ExpandListGroup group = new ExpandListGroup();
        ExpandListChild child = new ExpandListChild();

        int length = values[0].length;

        WorkourLogBuilder builder = null;

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            String exrcise = values[3][i];

            String restTime;
            String setTime;
            String weight;
            String reps;
            String comment;
            String sets;
            String speed;
            String distance;

            if (values[9][i] == null || values[9][i].equals(""))
                speed = mResources.getString(R.string.Undefined);
            else {
                if (data.getUnits().equals("metric"))
                    speed = values[9][i] + " " + mResources.getString(R.string.km_hour);
                else
                    speed = values[9][i] + " " + mResources.getString(R.string.miles_hour);
            }

            if (values[10][i] == null || values[10][i].equals(""))
                restTime = mResources.getString(R.string.Undefined);
            else
                restTime = getTimesPharsed(values[10][i]);

            if (values[6][i] == null || values[6][i].equals(""))
                setTime = mResources.getString(R.string.Undefined);
            else
                setTime = getTimesPharsed(values[6][i]);


            if (values[4][i] == null || values[4][i].equals(""))
                weight = mResources.getString(R.string.Undefined);
            else {
                if (data.getUnits().equals("metric"))
                    weight = values[4][i] + " " + mResources.getString(R.string.kg);
                else
                    weight = values[4][i] + " " + mResources.getString(R.string.lbs);
            }

            if (values[5][i] == null || values[5][i].equals(""))
                reps = mResources.getString(R.string.Undefined);
            else
                reps = values[5][i];

            if (values[11][i] == null || values[11][i].equals(""))
                comment = mResources.getString(R.string.Undefined);
            else
                comment = values[11][i];

            if (values[12][i] == null || values[12][i].equals(""))
                sets = mResources.getString(R.string.Undefined);
            else
                sets = values[12][i] + checkForFailedSets(values[1][i]);

            if (values[8][i] == null || values[8][i].equals(""))
                distance = mResources.getString(R.string.Undefined);
            else {
                if (data.getUnits().equals("metric"))
                    distance = values[8][i] + " " + mResources.getString(R.string.km);
                else
                    distance = values[8][i] + " " + mResources.getString(R.string.miles);
            }

            if(i == 0)
            {
                group = new ExpandListGroup();
                group.setName(exrcise, this);

                 Log.i("test", "1");

                if(data.getAerobic(exrcise))
                    builder = new WorkourLogBuilder(this, ANAEROBIC);
                else
                    builder = new WorkourLogBuilder(this, AEROBIC);

                builder.setWorkoutWeight(weight);
                builder.setReps(reps);
                builder.setSets(sets);
                builder.setWorkTime(setTime);
                builder.setRestTime(restTime);
                builder.setComment(comment);                    
                builder.setDistance(distance);
                builder.setSpeed(speed);
                builder.commintRow();

            }

            else if (i > 0 && exrcise.equals(values[3][i - 1]) == false && i == length - 1 == false) 
            {

                 Log.i("test", "2");

                View v = builder.build();

                child = new ExpandListChild();

                child.setLayouts((RelativeLayout) v);
                listChilds.add(child);

                group.setItems(listChilds);
                listAll.add(group);

                group = new ExpandListGroup();
                group.setName(exrcise, this);

                if(data.getAerobic(exrcise))
                    builder = new WorkourLogBuilder(this, ANAEROBIC);
                else
                    builder = new WorkourLogBuilder(this, AEROBIC);

                builder.setWorkoutWeight(weight);
                builder.setReps(reps);
                builder.setSets(sets);
                builder.setWorkTime(setTime);
                builder.setRestTime(restTime);
                builder.setComment(comment);                    
                builder.setDistance(distance);
                builder.setSpeed(speed);
                builder.commintRow();

              }

            else if (i == length - 1 && exrcise.equals(values[3][i - 1]) == false)  
            {
                 Log.i("test", "3");

                View v = builder.build();

                child = new ExpandListChild();
                child.setLayouts((RelativeLayout) v);
                listChilds.add(child);

                group.setItems(listChilds);
                listAll.add(group);

                group = new ExpandListGroup();
                group.setName(exrcise, this);

                if(data.getAerobic(exrcise))
                    builder = new WorkourLogBuilder(this, ANAEROBIC);
                else
                    builder = new WorkourLogBuilder(this, AEROBIC);

                    builder.setWorkoutWeight(weight);
                    builder.setReps(reps);
                    builder.setSets(sets);
                    builder.setWorkTime(setTime);
                    builder.setRestTime(restTime);
                    builder.setComment(comment);            
                    builder.setDistance(distance);
                    builder.setSpeed(speed);
                    builder.commintRow();

                v = builder.build();

                child = new ExpandListChild();
                child.setLayouts((RelativeLayout) v);
                listChilds.add(child);

                group.setItems(listChilds);
                listAll.add(group);

            }

            else if (i == length - 1 && exrcise.equals(values[3][i - 1]) == true)
            {
                 Log.i("test", "4");

                 if(data.getAerobic(exrcise))
                        builder = new WorkourLogBuilder(this, ANAEROBIC);
                    else
                        builder = new WorkourLogBuilder(this, AEROBIC);

                        builder.setWorkoutWeight(weight);
                        builder.setReps(reps);
                        builder.setSets(sets);
                        builder.setWorkTime(setTime);
                        builder.setRestTime(restTime);
                        builder.setComment(comment);                    
                        builder.setDistance(distance);
                        builder.setSpeed(speed);
                        builder.commintRow();

                View v = builder.build();

                child = new ExpandListChild();
                child.setLayouts((RelativeLayout) v);
                listChilds.add(child);

                group.setItems(listChilds);
                listAll.add(group);
            }

            else
            {
                 Log.i("test", "5");

                 builder.setWorkoutWeight(weight);
                    builder.setReps(reps);
                    builder.setSets(sets);
                    builder.setWorkTime(setTime);
                    builder.setRestTime(restTime);
                    builder.setComment(comment);                    
                    builder.setDistance(distance);
                    builder.setSpeed(speed);
                    builder.commintRow();
            }

        }

        ExpAdapter = new ExpandListAdapter(DatePage.this, listAll);
        ExpandList.setAdapter(ExpAdapter);

    }
```

When i look at the logcat i that the position log is always 0.

Why position is not increasing?

Comment: Your code is bad formatted and you don't show where `valuesArray` is filled/defined. Should I downvote you like you downvoted the valid answers?!

Comment: There answers are not working. position value increase is not connected to getItem.

Comment: and as I wrote in a comment: The answers are still valid! You should not downvote an answer that is pointing out mistakes in your code even if the answers are not solving your issue. Beside that: You still don't show the `valuesArray`. Are you sure that it is filled correctly?

Comment: Downvotes are for "This answer is not useful" not "This answer does not solve the worlds problems". The answers are useful because you are still doing that wrong.

Comment: CommitRow is do called. Is called from another activity. I wont post all my app code. I also can see the valuesArray is not empty from this log Log.i("count", valuesArray.size()+"");

Comment: @codeMagic my app may have a lot of bugs. But its not relevant to my question

Comment: @dasdasd you are not charging for your services, right? If your app has a lot of bugs, how can we know that one of those bugs is not a possible cause of this bug. Trust me, even if you post your entire repo, nobody would be able to get through it; your formatting and typos are your "maze". You are very well protected.

Comment: @Emmanuel I dont know if my app have bugs. But the answers i got is not relevant to my question. If you think that you need more info to answer my question than say that you can answer this.

Comment: @dasdasd so you need to show us more code. Where do you use this class and the adapter? Are you sure you are using the same instance? Why are you calculating +6 to the list size? Have you tried to use your adapter with a minimalistic static content?

Comment: Im calculating +6 because the first line in the gridview should be images, so the calculating  is my data+6 for the first line. Maybe its something with using Map object. I have used many time adapters all of the work great with the same code i use here. The only difference is that i have here an Map object.

Comment: @dasdasd I wish I could take credit but I didn't say that your app had bugs...I didn't look that closely. I just tried to explain to you the proper use of the up/down arrows next to answers

Answer (score 3):

You are not returning from `getItem()` correctly:

```
 public Object getItem(int position) {
                    return position;
                }
```

It should be:

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
                    return valuesArray.get(position);
                }
```

Comment: Not working. And getItem is not connection to getView.

Comment: Just because it does not solve your problem, there is no need to downvote! It is definitively a correct solution for your wrong `getItem()` method. Maybe you should be a bit cooperative...

Comment: We are trying to help you here, no need to be rude by leaving harsh comments and downvoting our answer.

Comment: position value increase is not connected to getItem.

Answer (score 2):

you have wrong in `getItem()`

```
 public Object getItem(int position) {
                return valuesArray.get(position);
            }
```

it should return an `Object` not an the position, so basically it is always returning 0

Comment: Not working. And getItem is not connection to getView.

Comment: `getItem` IS connected to your `getView`. the life cycle of the base adapter makes the `getView` takes it object from `getItem`. read more about it in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545770/how-does-baseadapter-works-in-when-we-extend-it). I dont understand the downvote!

Comment: position value increase is not connected to getItem.