# Android: The contents of the grid view are not getting displayed inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to implement two fragments in one activity. One with a list view in it and other with a grid view in it. The fragment with the grid view is not showing anything after execution.

It is showing blank when it is supposed to show all grid view elements

Here is the Pojo class

```
public class POJOMenuGrid {

String name;
String description;
int image;
public POJOMenuGrid(String name, String description, int image) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.image = image;
}

public POJOMenuGrid() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public int getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(int image) {
    this.image = image;
}



}
```

This is the adapter

```
public class MenuGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

Context context;
ArrayList<POJOMenuGrid> arr;
LayoutInflater inflater;



public MenuGridAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<POJOMenuGrid> arr) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.arr = arr;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arr.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.Adapter#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)
 */
@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single_item, null);
        System.out.println("in adapter 1");

    TextView itemName;
    TextView itemDescription;
    ImageView itemImage;
    Button plus;
    Button minus;
    TextView counter;
    System.out.println("in adapter 2");

    itemName  = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
    itemDescription  = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.itemDescription);
    counter  = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.counter);
    itemImage  = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
    plus = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.plus);
    minus = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.minus);
    System.out.println("in adapter 3");

    itemName.setText(arr.get(arg0).getName());
    itemDescription.setText(arr.get(arg0).getDescription());
    itemImage.setImageResource(arr.get(arg0).getImage());
    counter.setText("");

    System.out.println("in adapter 4");

    return v;
}


}
```

And the Fragment class

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment{

GridView fragment2Grid;
POJOMenuGrid pojo;
MenuGridAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<POJOMenuGrid> arr;


String[] name = {"Manchow Soup","Clear Soup","Mushroom Soup","Corn Soup","Tomato Soup"};
String[] desc = {"Soya water with capsicum , carrots , medium spicy"};
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_order_fragment_2, null);

    initialize();
    fragment2Grid = (GridView)v.findViewById(R.id.fragment2Grid);

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    arr.add(new POJOMenuGrid(name[i], desc[0], R.drawable.ic_launcher));

    System.out.println(arr.get(0).getName()+" "+arr.get(0).getDescription()+" ");



    adapter = new MenuGridAdapter(v.getContext(), arr);
    fragment2Grid.setAdapter(adapter);
    System.out.println("adapter set");


    return v;
}
private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    arr = new ArrayList<POJOMenuGrid>();
}
}
```

Comment: your getCount() returns 0?

Comment: is it compulsory to return some valid value from that function?

Comment: To say the truth I have no idea, but give it a try , I am saying this because I have never seen any code with them returning 0. Try returning the number of items in your getCount() and Id in getItemId() .. Try them out , I am checking the working to find out their significance

Comment: tell me if it solved the problem .. well according to this http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/BaseAdapter.java#BaseAdapter your adapter will be empty if getCount() returns 0

Answer (score 1):

You have not set the number of views in

```
@Override
getCount();
```

and id in

```
@Override
getItemId();
```

according to these links it is necessary to do that

```
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/GridView.java#GridView.lookForSelectablePosition%28int%2Cboolean%29
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545770/how-does-baseadapter-works-in-when-we-extend-it
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/BaseAdapter.java#BaseAdapter
```

If getCount() is set to zero your BaseAdapter will return empty, 'position' variable in the setAdapter() method of the GridView will always have an invalid value.

Comment: Just to complement your answer:
-> `getCount()`: must always return the number of items in the array, this basically tells the GridView how much items it'll have to draw.

-> `getIemId()`: this is a way for the GridView to differentiate it's children.

As an example, you can set it like this: `public int getCount(){ return arr.size(); }` and `public long getItemId(int arg0){ return arg0; }`

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I wil try it out